# If $\varphi$ is a normal faithful semifinite weight, is $\eta_\varphi(\mathfrak{n}_\varphi\cap\mathfrak{n}_\varphi^*)$ dense in $\mathfrak{H}_\varphi$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra and $\varphi: M_+\to [0, \infty]$ be a normal, faithful semifinite weight. Consider its associated semi-cyclic representation
$$\pi_\varphi: M\to B(\mathfrak{H}_\varphi)$$
(see Takesaki's second book, chapter VII for details).

Consider the associated map
$$\eta_\varphi: \mathfrak{n}_\varphi\to \mathfrak{H}_\varphi.$$

Is it true that $\eta_\varphi(\mathfrak{n}_\varphi\cap \mathfrak{n}_\varphi^*)$ is norm-dense in $\mathfrak{H}_\varphi$?

Attempt: If $\xi \perp \eta_\varphi(\mathfrak{n}_\varphi\cap \mathfrak{n}_\varphi^*)$, then for $x,y\in \mathfrak{n}_\varphi$
$$0 = \langle \xi, \eta_\varphi(x^*y) \rangle = \langle \pi_\varphi(x)\xi, \eta_\varphi(y)\rangle$$
so that $\pi_\varphi(\mathfrak{n}_\varphi)\xi=0$. Maybe this is sufficient to conclude that $\xi= 0$? I feel like non-degeneracy of $\pi_\varphi$ is relevant.

Thanks in advance for your help/input/comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is that $\mathfrak n_\phi$ is weak$^\ast$ dense in $M$, which follows from the semifiniteness of $\phi$: First, since $\mathfrak n_\phi$ is a left ideal of $M$, its weak$^\ast$ closure is of the form $Me$ for some projection $e\in M$. Thus $\mathfrak m_\phi\subset eMe$. Hence also the von Neumann algebra generated by $\mathfrak p_\phi$ is contained in $eMe$. As $\phi$ is semifinite, the von Neumann algebra generated by $\mathfrak p_\phi$ equals $M$ by Takesaki's definition. This implies that $e=1$, that is, the weak$^\ast$ closure of $\mathfrak n_\phi$ is $M$.

To conclude, use that $\pi_\phi$ is normal, hence the weak$^\ast$ closure of $\pi(\mathfrak n_\phi)$ contains $\pi_\phi(M)$. It follows from what you have shown that $\pi_\phi(M)\xi=0$. As $\pi_\phi$ is non-degenerate, $\xi$ must be zero.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That $\mathfrak{n}_\phi$ is weak*-dense can be proven faster, I think: We have $\mathfrak{m}_\varphi\subseteq \mathfrak{n}_\varphi$ and $\mathfrak{m}_\varphi$ is weak$^*$-dense by  the definition of semi-finiteness.

Comment: Maybe I'm too tired to see it, but why does $\pi_\phi(\mathfrak{n}_\varphi)\xi= 0$ and $\mathfrak{n}_\varphi$ weak$^*$-dense in $M$ imply that $\pi_\phi(M)\xi= 0$?

Is the following correct? The density and normality of $\pi_\phi$ show that $\pi_\phi(\mathfrak{m}_\varphi)$ is weak$^*$-dense in $\pi_\phi(\mathcal{M})$. But then we also have by general von Neumann algebra theory that $\pi_\phi(\mathfrak{m}_\phi)$ is strongly dense in $\pi_\phi(M)$ and the claim then follows (so I think somewhere you need to swap from weak*-density to strong density).

Comment: You're right with your first comment. As for the second comment, if $x_\alpha\to 1$ in the weak$^\ast$ topology (and $x_\alpha\in \mathfrak n_\phi$), then $0=\langle \xi,\pi_\phi(x_\alpha)\xi\rangle\to\lVert \xi\rVert^2$, hence $\xi=0$.

Comment: Thanks! I learn a lot from your comments and answers!

Comment: If you have time/interest, I have some other questions on MO which you might be able to answer.